# npm unable to install karma-jasmine on my mac

Tags: node.js, npm-install

When i install karma-jasmine on mac,it gives me errors:
 
`├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
└── karma-jasmine@0.3.8
npm WARN karma-jasmine@0.3.8 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.`

But,i have installed jasmine-core just before.

`npm install jasmine-core -g
/Users/hbowang/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.0/lib
└── jasmine-core@2.4.1`

Any body can help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error, but my package.json file is also missing so by creating package json file i am able to install jasmine-core and karma-jasmine.

For creating package.json file:

```
$ npm init
```

then after install jasmine-core:

```
 $ npm install jasmine-core
 $ npm install karma --save-dev
 $ npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
```

Hope it will help!!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you are installing jasmine-core with the global flag.
try installing it without the -g option and then retry.

notice the words UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY which suggests it wants it installed at the same level not globally maybe?

Comment: thanks for your answer,i have tried but it didn't work as your answer.